# .NET EF update database does not try to connect to database

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net, sqlclient

I have the following connection string:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
     options.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost;Database=SuperDB;User Id=sa;Password=MYPASSWORD;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"));
```

However when `.NET EF database update`, it does not create anything and just says (even if I enter a wrong password)

> Entity Framework Core 6.0.2 initialized 'ApplicationDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:6.0.2' with options: None

It does work locally if I remove the credentials and replace the server to `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB`, my default local server for SQL Server databases.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Aside... `Trusted_Connection=True;` will cause it to use Windows Authentication with the process's current authentication token - `User Id` and `Password` are completely ignored, which is why entering an incorrect password doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: There are a number of issues: `localhost` is for a full installation of SQL Server (*not* LocalDB) that is on your machine (although probably better to just use `.`). So what type of installation do you have, and where is it installed? And `Trusted_Connection` together with a username and password makes no sense, as @AlwaysLearning has said

Comment: Concerning my installation, I just have installed MSSQL on my Debian machine. As @AlwaysLearning said, removing `Trusted_Connection=True;` worked, I will post that as a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As AlwaysLearning said in the comments, removing `Trusted_Connection=True;` works as it causes the connection to use Windows Authentication (which works well locally obviously).